# Access Mongodb without mongod server

Tags: mongodb, javafx

I am currently working on javafx as front end and MongoDB as backend. I am running the mongod before start running my application. How to access the mongo database from the location (data/db/) instead of running the server everytime   before start running my application.

Comment: Simple answer: You can't.

Comment: maybe it could be better to run mongo as service/daemon?

Comment: Thanks @ Markus Then how can we create an application with mongodb as back end we need to just run application only to access database .If the user run the server everytime before he runs his application then it will be not an userfriendly one

Comment: Thanks @profesor79 how can we make mongo as a service.Its possible to run server in the application with the code but closing the server will cause an fil in execution of appliction

Comment: windows @profesor79

Comment: [try this](http://javabeat.net/developing-a-simple-todo-application-using-javafx-java-and-mongodb-part-1/)